# Calling a js function within shtml

Tags: javascript, shtml

I've been asked to fix a broken breadcrumb, but never worked with SSI shtml, so please bear with me.

They are trying to call a js function from within shtml that is being called by another shtml.

### main.shmtl

```
<!--#include virtual /shtml/abreadcrumb.shtml"-->
```

### abreadcrcumb.shtml

```
<script src="script/location/abreadcrumb.js">
<script>
     callabreadcrumb();
</script>
```

the js has been working until it was dropped into shtml, so I am not tinkering with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to close the first script tag:

```
<script src="script/location/abreadcrumb.js"></script>
<script>
     callabreadcrumb();
</script>
```

Comment: wow.... I feel slightly special now. Thank you. It won't let me accept yet - requires 8 more minutes?? I will though.